# Is Flex a Good option?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, geolocation, file-upload

I'm looking to learn and get efficient with an sdk. This along with making my very own interactive internet site. This site would be pretty simple in structure yet have a couple of tricky aspects like.

1. text uploading.
2. geo targetting.
3. nice gui.

among others.

Do you guys think flex Is the right way for me to go? If not any other advise would be greatly valuable as I wanna get of the right foot.

Comment: What do you mean by Text Uploading?

Comment: Your requirements are sparse.  Could you explain what the site will do?  Who are you targeting? Does this need to work on mobile? Is there large datasets involved? What technology are you using on the backend?

Comment: I voted to close; as this question is very vague and therefore impossibly to answer.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information about the needs of this site to propose the use of **any** technology. Anyone jumping on that bandwagon has something to _sell_ or a _limited_ _skill_ _set_.

Comment: Hi dennis,
we'll text uploading basically means users get to upload and share text.
yes, target users are ios, android and definitely the pc and mac.
thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Hold on a second.  Don't jump the gun here.  As I read your requirements, there is nothing that tells me that Flex is a good fit for you.

Don't get me wrong, I love Flex.  I use it a TON in my day job.  I also use and love Silverlight (another very capable RIA framework).  BUT, that doesn't mean that I would jump to either of them when creating a website with the three requirements that you suggested.

Flex and Silverlight are great for data-driven web APPLICATIONS with solid user interfaces.  They integrate media really well and they have quite a rapid development cycle.  They are not necessarily great for web SITES.  Notice that Adobe, themselves, have not written their web site in Flex.  The user experience is actually downgraded when using Flex or Silverlight in places where it is not a strong fit.

HTML/Javascript/CSS will take you a long way without the need for Flex or Silverlight.  Although some people suggested that Flex works in Android, Blackberry Playbook and iOS, it will not work in the browser for iOS and the browser experience on Android is unusable on most devices.  HTML/Javascrpt/CSS will take you anywhere.

That is not to suggest that I am suggesting HTML/Javascript/CSS either.

Again, I don't have any idea what your expected reach is for your site.  We simply don't know enough to give you a good recommendation.  ANY web technology (Statefull RIAs or Stateless HTTP-based stacks) will sufficiently meet your three requirements.

Tell us more on why you want Flex, and we might be able to answer this more completely.  Certainly do not assume that Flex is "Definately" the right way to go based on two recommendations from people with less than 100 cred points.

Comment: Thanks brian for your indept views I really appreciate It, I'll try to be detailed this time around.
We'll the thing Is, my site would revolve around these 3 basic functionalities that I previously stated. I would definitely add certain other capabilities as the site rolls along and ideas fill my head.
So what your saying Is flex doesn't work on ios and android(no good enough) that gives me reason enough to pass on flex because I on a whole believe that the site might really take of on the handheld at large.
So yes, the user base Is from the box and the handhelds as well, (iphone and android)

Comment: Also, I was looking at city wise targeting of content, I know this might be a little off target but your views would definitely help a great deal. 
I'm talking about geo targetting(city wise)
Thanks again, I appreciate It.

Comment: @parastar: I am not saying that Flex doesn't work on iOS or well on Android, because it does for NATIVE apps. But if you are building a browser-based website, Flex will not be native... it will live in the browser. If your requirement is to run in the browser on iOS, then Flex is out. Not recommended in Android either. I would stick with an HTML based framework.  There are tons out there.  To name a few: ASP.Net MVC, Ruby on Rails, Django, CakePHP and Java/Spring. This is NOT an exhaustive list. At that point, it becomes a matter of preference because they will all handle your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely RIA(Rich Internet Application) is what you need, so the best option is Flex because,

1.Application for Web
2.Application for Desktop(AIR)
3.Application for Android
4.Application for Blackberry
5.Application for IOS

All upper points are cover by one IDE/SDK and that is FLEX.

```
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html?promoid=DINIJ
```

Enjoy.

Comment: thank you guys, I'll look into flex for my needs, thank you again

Comment: -1.  No, this is NOT "Definitely" what this user needs.  What in the requirements tells you that your reasons have anything to do with the needs?  Plus, saying that you can develop apps for the Blackberry is not completely accurate.  Blackberry Playbook only.  Silverlight is also a very capable RIA framework... if you want a RIA framework at all...

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Flex is right way for you to create RIA Website.

Comment: okay, so with flex I can integrate independant snippets of code from sites like codango easily as well?

Comment: -1 The OP never said anything about wanting to create a RIA website.  If you DO want a RIA website, Silverlight is also a way to go.